# Spring - Hibernate Manual Transaction

Tags: spring, hibernate

Hibernate, I don't want to use @Transactional Annotaion,
I want to create it manually.
SO how can i create Manual Transaction in it..?

Comment: Do you want to use non annotation based hibernate or you don't want to use hibernate transaction framework & want to use some other transaction management framework?

Answer (score 0):

You could use programmatic transaction manager [see here](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-transaction-handle-example/)